# Is https://www.bitaddress.org/ safe to create a paperwallet?

Tags: paper-wallet, coldstorage

I want to create a paper wallet for cold storage and am not sure of the best way to do that. I heard of https://www.bitaddress.org/, but is it safe if booted from an offline PC?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, because the 100% of entropy (randomness) is generated by the user.

---

Just make sure you're downloading it from https://github.com/pointbiz/bitaddress.org > green "clone and download" button > download as zip.

Comment: @MCCS Thank you man! Is there a page that explains how to withdraw from the paper wallet later on, to another address?

Comment: @Hollossy Your wallet (Electrum preferred) > Sweep private keys. Instructions for Electrum: Set up your wallet as you would do normally > Wallet > Private Keys > Sweep

Comment: @MCCS Aren't there issues with the Electrum wallets?

Comment: @Hollossy The only issue with Electrum is that usual Electrum wallets can't import private keys, but instead they can "sweep", which means withdrawing the private key funds to one of Electrum's address. That is not a problem.

Comment: @MCCS so there may be a problem when I want to withdraw from the Electrum wallet? Sorry for my lack of understanding... And thank you for all the help!

Comment: @Hollossy No, there won't be any problems.

Comment: @Hollossy If there is problem (100% there shouldn't be): Electrum asks for wallet file every time you run it. Change the wallet name from `wallet` to `paperwallet` or something to create a new wallet. Then choose "import Bitcoin private keys". That's your backup plan.

Comment: Thank you!! You use that too? Or would you suggest a brainwallet?

Comment: @Hollossy Nope, bitaddress.org's brainwallet can be cracked easily, but if you really want to use a brainwallet, use https://keybase.io/warp/ .